# Generate static API routes in nextjs

Tags: javascript, next.js

I have data (JSON) in a file that I want to expose through an API. I know the data at build time but I don't know how to create static API routes or even expose the files through the API routes statically.

I googled two solutions for this:

- Create a static page that returns a JSON file (couldn't find a solution, it always returned HTML).
- Use the pages/api/[something] to generate the API (but it seems to always be dynamic).

My last resort is to try to access the file through the function on the /pages/api/[something].js but this is dynamic and not static.

The dynamic function that comes by default in /pages/api/hello.js folder:

```js
export default (req, res) => {  
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.json({ name: "John Doe" });
};
```

What is the typical strategy here? I feel that I'm missing something.

Comment: Have you tried placing the `data.json` inside `public/api` folder? It's not technically `api`, but it should serve the static file on `/api/data.json` route.

Comment: I can access the markdown files directly, but those don't do the gray-matter processing. I'm probably being too nitpicky.

Comment: Ah, I remember the problem with this option: I need to check inside the files for the title to generate the slug.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, this is the dynamic way I found to generate the API dynamically:

```js
// on file /pages/api/[article].js
import { getArticle } from "../../lib/api";

export default (req, res) => {

  // It gets an article from a file, also can be used with getStaticProps
  const article = getPost({article: req.article}); 
  
  res.statusCode = 200;

  // returns the JSON.
  res.json(article);
}
```

I'd still prefer to have it static to not need any serverless functions running.

Answer (score 1):

`Use the pages/api/[something] to generate the API (but it seems to always be dynamic).`

No it's not dynamic. From `[something].js`,if you export **getStaticPath**(this will generate static routes for you) and **getStaticProps**(this will inject the data to be served from corresponding routes), `next build` will have your static files generated, and ready to be served as api pages with raw json data.

Hope this had been what you were trying to solve.

Comment: Very likely I am missing something, there is no way to `next export` static files generated on build time. I think this is what @artur-carvalho meant.